# XPath not working

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, xpath

I am trying to read the entitysets within the EDMX file from Entity Framework.

The EDMX file (XML format) has the following layout:

```
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
   <edmx:Runtime>
      <edmx:ConceptualModels>
         <Schema Namespace="Model" Alias="Self" p1:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns:p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
               <EntityContainer Name="EntityModel" p1:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
                  <EntitySet Name="TableName" EntityType="Model.TableName" />
```

I am using following XPath to get all EntitySet Nodes within the EntityContainer:

```
/edmx:Edmx/edmx:Runtime/edmx:ConceptualModels/Schema/EntityContainer/EntitySet
```

but I am getting no result with this C# code:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument("pathtoedmx");
var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("edmx", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx");
ns.AddNamespace("annotation", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation");
ns.AddNamespace("p1", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation");
ns.AddNamespace("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm");
var entitySets = xdoc.SelectNodes("/edmx:Edmx/edmx:Runtime/edmx:ConceptualModels/Schema/EntityContainer/EntitySet", ns);
```

Already got the XPath from this tool (http://qutoric.com/xmlquire/), because I started not trusting my own XPath skills but it tells me the same XPath I was already using.

If I remove the **"/Schema/EntityContainer/EntitySet"** part its finding the **"/edmx:Edmx/edmx:Runtime/edmx:ConceptualModels"**, but not further on already tried to specify the "edmx" namespace ("edmx:/Schema") but no difference.

Hope you can help me out, already banging my head against the table. :)

Comment: Does it need to bee XPath if not, you may want to use LinqToXml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces are a convention on how to combine two different XML dialects into a single document. Those prefixes really doesn't matter as long you keep your URI component exactly the same. For instance, take something like this:

```
ns.AddNamespace("xxx", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx");
Console.WriteLine(xdoc.SelectNodes("/xxx:Edmx", ns).Count); // 1
```

You'll get one node because your namespace URI matched, despite your "wrong" namespace prefix.

If you have an attribute named `xmlns`, current element and it's children will inherits that namespace URI.

In your case, your root element doesn't have a default namespace and that's ok. But your `Schemas` element **does** have a namespace and you need to inform it. I came with this code:

```
// change "" to "edm"
ns.AddNamespace("edm", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm");
var entitySets = xdoc.SelectNodes("/edmx:Edmx/edmx:Runtime/edmx:ConceptualModels/edm:Schema/edm:EntityContainer/edm:EntitySet", ns);
```

Comment: Thanks, you hit the nail. :)